# Keeping values in one row based on values in different row and different column

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to make a new DF for the values in `tdif` only when `NP==0` in the row directly above it?

```
    Subject tdif NP
1       KM3 63.8  0
2       KM3  4.6  1
3       KM3 70.6  0
4       KM3 30.4  1
5       KM3 44.8  0
6       KM3 12.1  1
7       KM3 27.1  1
8       KM3 36.0  0
9       KM3 38.0  1
10      KM3  0.1  1
```

So, a desired output would be:

```
    Subject tdif NP
1       KM3  4.6  1
2       KM3 30.4  1
3       KM3 12.1  1
4       KM3 38.0  1
```

I'm happy using `tidyverse` or any other packages (I've used it to manipulate my raw data to this point), but I've had a hell of a time finding help for this specific type of data manipulation in R so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `which` to get the row index where `NP == 0` and add 1 to it to get next row.

```
df[which(df$NP == 0) + 1, ]

#  Subject tdif NP
#2     KM3  4.6  1
#4     KM3 30.4  1
#6     KM3 12.1  1
#9     KM3 38.0  1
```

If you have 0 in your last row this might give you an additional row with `NA`s which you can remove by comparing the values with `nrow(df)` Or use `dplyr::lag`.

---

With `dplyr` `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(lag(NP) == 0)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell with my actual data this works. Thank you! How exactly does it work, though? I'm still pretty new with understanding code syntax.

Comment: @Kevin `which(df$NP == 0)` returns row number where `NP == 0` we add 1 to it to get the next row and use this index to subset the dataframe whereas `lag` just selects those rows whose previous `NP` value was 0.